# How to extract Postal code from V3 Google maps API

Tags: json, google-maps

I am using the following to get a the lat-lng from a geocode..

```
  $latitude = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
  $longitude = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;
```

How do I extract the Postal code from ...

```
{
  "status": "OK",
  "results": [ {
    "types": [ "street_address" ],
    "formatted_address": "1600 Amphitheatre Pkwy, Mountain View, CA 94043, USA",
    "address_components": [ {
      "long_name": "1600",
      "short_name": "1600",
      "types": [ "street_number" ]
    }, {
      "long_name": "Amphitheatre Pkwy",
      "short_name": "Amphitheatre Pkwy",
      "types": [ "route" ]
    }, {
      "long_name": "Mountain View",
      "short_name": "Mountain View",
      "types": [ "locality", "political" ]
    }, {
      "long_name": "California",
      "short_name": "CA",
      "types": [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
    }, {
      "long_name": "United States",
      "short_name": "US",
      "types": [ "country", "political" ]
    }, {
      "long_name": "94043",
      "short_name": "94043",
      "types": [ "postal_code" ]
    } ],
    "geometry": {
      "location": {
        "lat": 37.4219720,
        "lng": -122.0841430
      },
      "location_type": "ROOFTOP",
      "viewport": {
        "southwest": {
          "lat": 37.4188244,
          "lng": -122.0872906
        },
        "northeast": {
          "lat": 37.4251196,
          "lng": -122.0809954
        }
      }
    }
  } ]
}
```

Answer (score 13):

You could use the following function to extract any address component:

```
function extractFromAdress(components, type){
    for (var i=0; i<components.length; i++)
        for (var j=0; j<components[i].types.length; j++)
            if (components[i].types[j]==type) return components[i].long_name;
    return "";
}
```

To extract the postal code you call:

```
extractFromAdress(results[0].address_components, "postal_code");
```

But you could also get other interesting info like:

```
extractFromAdress(results[0].address_components, "route");
extractFromAdress(results[0].address_components, "locality");
extractFromAdress(results[0].address_components, "country");
```

etc...

Answer (score 0):

I'd say you'd need to loop through `results.address_components`.  On each iteration check if the types array contains "postal_code".  If it does, save that to a variable, and probably break out of the loop as well.  Although it might be worth investigating to see if the postal_code is always in address_component[5], which would save you having to loop.